# Lighting on the interface

Tags: 3d-view, interface, lighting

I have a problem with the lighting in my project. I can't see any type of lighting, I can see it only on the render result. A few days ago I saw my environment texture on the interface but now I can't see it here, only in render result. It looks like I have turned off lighting view on the interface but I don't know how.
Thank you in advance for any kind of help.
Everything is on the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are "scene world" and "scene lights" checked in the viewport shading settings menu (the little window that appears when you click the arrow next to the render preview buttons)?

Comment: You right, it was the problem. Thank you soooo much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that either "scene lights", or "scene world" is unchecked in the Viewport Shading settings menu. See image:

[image: ViewportShadingSettings]